# How can I pass Facebook Share API an object with no (real) canonical url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, url

Information:

- Project is in Angular, makes heavy use of '#' and '?' in URLs, where all objects have a unique URL
- Running on Apache 2.4
- The "Share" pane is an Angular modal, an HTML template
- Site being developed on localhost
- Goal is to be able to share the individual objects from the app, not just the entire site

What I have tried:

- Configured Apache to accept fake canonical URLs, rewrite them as Angular dynamic URLs, my application formats the dynamic URLs to "canonical" URLs replacing all special symbols with "/"... This piece is working fine now
- Plug-ins for "social sharing on angular" leave the Share pop-up with a truncated URL, with only a path to the root folder (full path is visible and correct in address bar as GET param)
- Manually calling FB.ui() passes the correct URL, but Facebook throws "Could not find object at URL"
- Adding dynamically generated "meta" tags to the HTML template (longshot) seems to have no effect.

Could this be an issue because I'm sending a "localhost" URL for testing? Or does Facebook really require that all shared content be located at it's own root-level document with "meta" tags inside "head"?

Comment: _“Could this be an issue because I'm sending a "localhost" URL for testing?”_ – of course; how do you expect Facebook to read any OG meta data from _your_ localhost?

Comment: That forms the premise of my question. Given that FB can't scrape my localhost, how (if possible) does one test their share posts before deploying publicly? My workaround for the meantime is to use the Feed API endpoint and pass custom sharepost data through query parameters. Works for FB, but Google+ for example does not provide ANY method for customizing the share posts, other than structuring HTML for it to scrape.

Comment: You _need_ to put it on a web server that is reachable over the internet. If you don’t want to make it “public” at the same time – then implement some kind of access control, based on the `User-Agent` header the FB scraper sends (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#scraperinfo) or IP addresses it uses (they had it documented somewhere how to get those.)

Comment: Thank you for that insight. I'll configure the server to only serve it to user-agents i need to test on. Much appreciated